# Шаблон скидки ocstore 2.1.0.2

Tags: php, opencart, filter

Использую ocstore 2.1.0.2 . Есть ли возможность редактирования схемы через админку страницы

```
example.com/index.php?route=product/special
```

Интересует конкретно возможность применения фильтров не дефолтных (количество товаров на странице и сортировка), а тех, которые создавались в админке в разделе фильтры.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял смысл вопроса, то Вам надо в админке (в разделе Схемы) создать новую схему: название, например, Акции, и указать путь:

product/special

И уже на эту схему вешать нужные модули.